# How do I find integers that solve the following inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Give integers $a,b,c,x,y,z$ such that:

$$|a|+|b|+|c| < |x|+|y|+|z|$$ and $$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$

I have no idea when this would ever be true, it seems like it would never be true. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $x=y=z=1$ and $a=b=0,c=2$

Comment: @kingW3 Note that there is a strict inequality involved.

Comment: @Allawonder $3>2$ and $\sqrt4>\sqrt3$ both strict.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because of the strict inequality involved and the constraint to integer values only, the problem has no solution. To see this, let the ordered tuples of integers $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ represent points in the integer grid $\mathrm R^3.$ Then we can show that the problem $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\le |a|+|b|+|c|< |x|+|y|+|z|$$ has no such solutions, by showing that if the sum of coordinate lengths of one of the points, say $A,$ is less than that of the other, say $B,$ then $A$ is strictly closer to the origin than $B,$ contradicting the given conditions.

Thus, without loss of generality let all coordinates be nonnegative (we're in the first octant), and let $p=a+b+c<x+y+z=q.$ Then since we're dealing with integers, assume again without loss of generality that $p=q-1.$ Then any nonnegative three-partition of $p$ will have at least one coordinate less than those of $q.$ It then follows that $A$ is on a sphere of smaller radius than $B.$